# Call Google Place Api on EditText

Tags: android

I am using google place API in my app and it's working perfectly when using fragment but, I want to call all the functionality on click on EditText. How to call that?

```
PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
            .Builder(this)
            .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .build();

    try {
        startActivityForResult(builder.build(this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException | GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi
            .getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, null);
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces) {
            for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {


            }
            likelyPlaces.release();
        }
    });
```

If I am commenting this code from PlaceAutoCompleteFragment to before try block, yet it's working, so I don't understand from where it's is working and how to correct that:

```
    PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);

    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
           // Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            //Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
        }
    });


try {
            Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)
                            .build(this);
            startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException | GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
        }
}
```

Here I am calling ActivityResult:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);
            String toastMsg = String.format("Place: %s", place.getName());
            Toast.makeText(this, toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    if (requestCode == PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(this, data);
            //Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName());
        } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {
            Status status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(this, data);
            // TODO: Handle the error.
           // Log.i(TAG, status.getStatusMessage());

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // The user canceled the operation.
        }
    }
}
```